# send a data to another form by choosing datagridview row and pressing a button (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` in my form that shows some data.

The selection mode is `FullRowSelect`.

I want when user select a row and then press edit button, it store ID text from selected row to a variable and pass to second form (to use in queries).

Also, the edit button must have a keyboard shortcut, for example `F2` (after selecting the row and pressing the key data will be passed to the new form).

I find way to do it by double clicking on row using `DataGridView` event, but I don't know how to it by using a button!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `KeyDown` event to your `DataGridView`

```
private void dataGridView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue != 113) //Keyvalue 113 is key 'F2'
       return;
    DataGridView gridView = sender as DataGridView;
    if (gridView == null)
       return;

    if(gridView.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
       return;

    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = gridView.SelectedRows[0]; //Retrive select row
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in selectedRow.Cells)
    {
       object val = cell.Value; //Your cell values in selected row
     }
}
```

Also, see [this link](https://asawicki.info/nosense/doc/devices/keyboard/key_codes.html) for more`KeyValue`s.

Comment: Can you explain your code? I don't understand it

Comment: I think its easier if you ask about specific parts of the code you don't understand rather than me explaining the whole method. So, anything in particular you want to ask about?

Comment: (sorry my English is not good) first, lets forget about keyboard shortcut, I want user select a row and then press a button to send only ID which is in first filed of DataGridView (index 0) - in second form, ID will be show in a Label and will be used in Queries

Comment: @gohar iranian 
Yes I understand. My code shows you how to retrieve the selected row in the grid view with a button press. I assumed you yourself would be able to add the code for the new form... In the `foreach` loop at the end you can get your selected rows values. Just replace this loop with the line `string id = selectedRow.Cells[0].Value.Tostring()` and then send it to your new form.